# запись и удаление данных через одну форму POST, php и mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Скажем есть 1 форма отправки POST, с переменной value1.
В базе есть 3 ячейки value1, value2, value3

Как сделать так что бы после отправки данной формы значение переменной в форме поменялось на value2 и соотвественно на value3, при этом если в базе есть запись value1 и value3, то выводится форма для отправки с первым ближайшим пустым значением, те value2

Так же у каждого этого значения после записи появляется кнопка "удалить данное значение".

Если в общем, то это загрузка изображений по очереди, вывод их с последующим удалением для каждого.

Накидайте пожалуйста идеи как это реализовать или как еще можно реализовать загрузку по очереди картинок, вывод и удаление по очереди. **Интересует только чистый PHP**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас запрос интересует или написание такого сайта на php? Попытайтесь разделить вашу задачу на множество разных.

Comment: меня интересует алгоритм как это делать? циклом, условиями или как вообще можно добавить последовательно и удалить хаотично при этом записывать данные через одно поле

Comment: может быть есть какой-то пример, очень простой что бы смысл был понятен куда двигаться. Как менять переменную в форме?